# What is the most stable AWS EC2 region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, uptime

I'm wondering if anyone has compiled any stats about which region in AWS has experienced the fewest outages, and/or has the best uptime percentage? From my very anecdotal experience US-East-1 (the default region) has had way more outages than the others I'm using, but it would be interesting to see some statistical validation of this hypothesis, or if other people have a similar experience.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt worry about which region is most stable. If everyone acted on it, would it not reduce that regions stability? Weigh up the cost of the risk of losing a region, compare that to the cost of mitigating the risk by spreading yourself over many regions, and pay accordingly.

Comment: Only if the region loses stability through increased usage. Which would be a bad thing :)